# Why is my keras LSTM model predicting the same NER tag for NLP multiclassification problem?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp, neural-network, named-entity-recognition

I'm using CoLL2023 dataset as input and word2vec as the embeddings

```
import gensim.downloader
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
import string

# Load the Word2Vec model
w2v = gensim.downloader.load('word2vec-google-news-300')

# Load and preprocess the data
def load_and_preprocess_data(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        conll_data = file.read().splitlines()
    
    # Clean rows with empty lines
    conll_data = [line for line in conll_data if line.strip() != '']
    
    # Split each line into columns
    conll_data = [line.split() for line in conll_data]
        # Remove punctuation from each word
    for i in range(len(conll_data)):
        conll_data[i] = [word.strip(string.punctuation) for word in conll_data[i]]
    
    return conll_data

train_data = load_and_preprocess_data('data/eng.train')
test_data = load_and_preprocess_data('data/eng.testb')
dev_data = load_and_preprocess_data('data/eng.testa')

# Create DataFrames
columns = ['word', 'POS', 'NP', 'label']
train_df = pd.DataFrame(train_data, columns=columns)
test_df = pd.DataFrame(test_data, columns=columns)
dev_df = pd.DataFrame(dev_data, columns=columns)

# Create labels for NER
label_to_id = {label: i for i, label in enumerate(train_df['label'].unique())}

for index, row in train_df.iterrows():
    train_df.at[index, 'label_id'] = label_to_id[row['label']]
for index, row in test_df.iterrows():
    test_df.at[index, 'label_id'] = label_to_id[row['label']]
for index, row in dev_df.iterrows():
    dev_df.at[index, 'label_id'] = label_to_id[row['label']]

texts = train_df['word'].tolist()  # list of text samples
labels_index = label_to_id  # dictionary mapping label name to numeric id
labels = train_df['label_id'].tolist()  # list of label ids
print(labels)

validation_texts = dev_df['word'].tolist()  # list of text samples
labels_index = label_to_id  # dictionary mapping label name to numeric id

# Step 1: Create a label mapping dictionary based on your training labels
label_mapping = {}

# Iterate over the unique labels in your training dataset
for label in train_df['label'].unique():
    # Map the original label to a consistent label
    label_mapping[label] = label

# Step 2: Replace validation labels with consistent labels
dev_labels = [label_mapping[label] for label in dev_df['label']]
dev_df['labels'] = dev_labels
for index, row in dev_df.iterrows():
    dev_df.at[index, 'label_id'] = label_to_id[row['label']]
validation_labels = dev_df['label_id'].tolist() 

print(len(dev_df['label'].unique()))

test_texts = test_df['word'].tolist()  # list of text samples
labels_index = label_to_id  # dictionary mapping label name to numeric id
test_labels = test_df['label_id'].tolist()  # list of label ids

from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np

# Define MAX_NB_WORDS and MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH before using them
MAX_NB_WORDS = 10000  # Define your desired maximum number of words
MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 100  # Define your desired maximum sequence length

# Tokenize your text data
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=MAX_NB_WORDS)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(texts)
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(texts)

word_index = tokenizer.word_index
print('Found %s unique tokens.' % len(word_index))

data = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH, padding='post', truncating='post')

labels = to_categorical(np.asarray(labels))
print('Shape of data tensor:', data.shape)
print('Shape of label tensor:', labels.shape)

# Assuming you have separate validation and test datasets
x_val = pad_sequences(tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(validation_texts), maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH, padding='post', truncating='post')
y_val = padded_validation_labels = to_categorical(validation_labels, num_classes=8)
print(y_val)
print('Shape of data tensor:', x_val.shape)
print('Shape of label tensor:', y_val.shape)

x_test = pad_sequences(tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(test_texts), maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH, padding='post', truncating='post')
y_test = to_categorical(np.asarray(test_labels))
print('Shape of data tensor:', x_test.shape)
print('Shape of label tensor:', y_test.shape)
to_categorical(np.asarray(test_labels))

embeddings_index = {}

# Iterate through words in the model's vocabulary and their corresponding vectors
for index, word in enumerate(w2v.index_to_key):
    embeddings_index[word] = w2v[word]

print('Found %s word vectors.' % len(embeddings_index))

# print vector for the word 'the'
print(embeddings_index['the'])

EMBEDDING_DIM = 300  # Adjust this to match the dimension of your Word2Vec model

embedding_matrix = np.zeros((len(word_index) + 1, EMBEDDING_DIM))
for word, i in word_index.items():
    embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        # Words not found in embedding index will be all-zeros.
        embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector

from keras.layers import Embedding

embedding_layer = Embedding(len(word_index) + 1,
                            EMBEDDING_DIM,
                            weights=[embedding_matrix],
                            input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                            trainable=False)


from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
import string
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding, LSTM, Dense
from keras.metrics import Precision, Recall, F1Score

# Create an LSTM model
model = Sequential()

# Add an Embedding layer with pre-trained Word2Vec weights
model.add(Embedding(len(word_index) + 1, EMBEDDING_DIM, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH, trainable=False))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='softmax'))
# Add an LSTM layer with a specified number of units (you can adjust this)
LSTM_UNITS = 64
model.add(LSTM(LSTM_UNITS, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
# 
# Add a Dense output layer with the number of labels as units and 'softmax' activation
model.add(Dense(len(labels_index), activation='softmax'))


model.compile(
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=['accuracy', F1Score(average='micro')]
)


# Train the model
EPOCHS = 10  # You can adjust this
BATCH_SIZE = 10  # You can adjust this
history = model.fit(data, labels, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))

# Evaluate the model on the test data
scores = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
test_f1 = scores[model.metrics_names.index('f1_score')]
print("Test F1 Score:", test_f1)


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Reverse the word and label index dictionaries
index_to_word = {v: k for k, v in word_index.items()}
index_to_labels = {v: k for k, v in label_to_id.items()}  # Replace label_to_id with your mapping

# Initialize lists to store original texts and predicted labels
# original_texts = [index_to_word.get(i, '?') for i in x_test.flatten()]  # Flatten if x_test is 2D
predicted_labels_list = []

# Make predictions
predictions = model.predict(x_test)
predicted_indices = np.argmax(predictions, axis=-1).flatten()  # Flatten if predictions is 2D

# Translate numerical indices back to original labels
predicted_labels = []
for i in predicted_indices:
    label = index_to_labels.get(i, '?')
    predicted_labels.append(label)
    
# Convert lists into DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Original_Texts': test_texts,
    'true labels id': test_labels,
    'true labels': test_df['label'].tolist(),
    'Predicted Labels id': predicted_indices,
    'Predicted Labels': predicted_labels
})

df.head(30)
```

I've tried adding more dense layers, changing num of epochs, etc. but the output is still the same:

Original_Texts  true labels id  true labels Predicted Labels id Predicted Labels
0   SOCCER  1.0 O   1   O
1       1.0 O   1   O
2   JAPAN   4.0 I-LOC   1   O
3   GET 1.0 O   1   O
4   LUCKY   1.0 O   1   O
5   WIN 1.0 O   1   O
6       1.0 O   1   O
7   CHINA   3.0 I-PER   1   O
8   IN  1.0 O   1   O
9   SURPRISE    1.0 O   1   O
10  DEFEAT  1.0 O   1   O
11      1.0 O   1   O
12  Nadim   3.0 I-PER   1   O
13  Ladki   3.0 I-PER   1   O
14  AL-AIN  4.0 I-LOC   1   O
15      1.0 O   1   O